# Запретить использование дополнительных GET параметров в запросе. Swagger документация

Tags: документация, swagger

Для описание REST API я использую open API спецификацию (в народе известную как swagger документация). Я хочу запретить пользователям, которые используют мое API, передачу дополнительных GET параметров - которые не описаны в документации, как мне это сделать?

Comment: Вы имееете в виду «как написать в документации, что дополнительные параметры запрещены» или «как запретить их отправку через страницу со сваггером»?

Comment: Ну вообще это одно и тоже по сути, мне надо осуществить запрет на уровне документации, если это корректно описать, это будет видно в swagger-ui и соответственно валидацию swaggera это не пройдет и не отправится

Comment: А вообще документация к API, еще используется для валидации поступающих к приложению запросов)

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести пример валидного и невалидного запроса? Что сервер будет отвечать на такой запрос (потому что отправить его всё равно технически можно будет)?

Comment: Пусть будет вот такой endpoint например. 
**Валидный** (GET параметр __host__ описан в swagger схеме):
__GET "https://api.service.d/v1/detect/?host=myhost.ru"__

**Невалидный** (GET параметр __bad__ не описан в схеме, поэтому при получении этого параметра api должно отдать 400-ый ответ): 
__GET "https://api.service.d/v1/detect/?host=myhost.ru&bad=val"__

Comment: Не увидел тогда уведомление о том, что вы мне ответили. Что в итоге, решили задачу? Может быть, напишете ответ?

Comment: К сожалению так и не нашел ответ, хотя еще долго искал, но так как в спецификации OpenAPI 2.0 об этом ничего, поэтому я делаю вывод что это не реализуемо..

Comment: а разве нельзя считать, что разрешены только явно описанные параметры? Есть же принцип GIGO: garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: Конечно можно это реализовать, без проблем, но это уже вне спецификации будет

Comment: Я имею в виду, что в любом API разрешены только документированные параметры, об этом не нужно писать отдельно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как в спецификации OpenAPI 2.0 об этом ничего, я делаю вывод что ограничение дополнительных GET параметров не поддерживается..